# Как сделать чтобы узел TreeView можно было переименовать?

Tags: c#, winforms

Для пробы работы с TreeView использую следующий код.

```
private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            CreateRootNode();

            treeView1.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
            foreach (TreeNode RootNode in treeView1.Nodes)
            {
                RootNode.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip2;
                foreach (TreeNode ChildNode in RootNode.Nodes)
                    ChildNode.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip2;
            }
}

        // Заполнение дерева узлами
public void CreateRootNode()
{
            // Create the root node.
            // Создаем корневой узел.
            TreeNode docNode = new TreeNode("Documents");

            // Add some additional nodes.
            // Добавьте некоторые дополнительные узлы.
            docNode.Nodes.Add("phoneList.doc");
            docNode.Nodes.Add("resume.doc");

            // Add the root nodes to the TreeView.
            // Добавьте корневые узлы в TreeView.
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(docNode);
        }

        // Добавить Корневой
        private void AddNewRootToolStripMenuItem_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            frmEnterText frm = new frmEnterText();
            frm.ShowDialog();
            string TempNodeText = frm.txtNodeName.Text;
            frm.Dispose();

            if (TempNodeText.Trim() != "")
            {
                TreeNode _Node = new TreeNode();
                _Node.Text = TempNodeText;
                _Node.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip2;
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(_Node);
            }
        }

        private void ClearAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
        }


        // Добавить Подчинённый
        private void AddChildRootToolStripMenuItem_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            frmEnterText frm = new frmEnterText();
            frm.ShowDialog();
            string TempNodeText = frm.txtNodeName.Text;
            frm.Dispose();

            if (TempNodeText.Trim() != "")
            {
                TreeNode _Node = new TreeNode();
                _Node.Text = TempNodeText;
                _Node.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip2;
                treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(_Node);
            }
        }

        // Переименовать
        private void RenameToolStripMenuItem_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            frmEnterText frm = new frmEnterText();
            frm.ShowDialog();
            string TempNodeText = frm.txtNodeName.Text;
            frm.Dispose();
            TreeNode SelectedNode = treeView1.SelectedNode;
            if (TempNodeText.Trim() != "")
                SelectedNode.Text = TempNodeText;
        }

        // Удалить 
        private void DeleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            treeView1.SelectedNode.Remove();
        }
```

При закрытии формы дерево сохраняется в XML файл (в данном коде не рассматривается).
По средствам контекстного меню код выполняет работу с узлами:
- добавить;
- удалить;
- переименовать.

При выполнении "Переименовать" новое имя узла вводится в отдельном диалоге.

Вопрос.
Как сделать чтобы "переименовать" можно было выполнять в узле дерева (см. скрин)?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какие с этим проблемы? ([линк](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/893068/WPF-TreeView-with-in-place-editing))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможность редактирования узлов контролируется свойством [`TreeView.LabelEdit`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.labeledit?view=netframework-4.7.2). Из документации:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the label text of the tree nodes can be edited.
>
> Устанавливает либо возвращает значение, обозначающее возможно ли редактировать тексты меток узлов дерева.

Для включения редактирования нужно установить свойство в true:

```
treeView1.LabelEdit = true;
```

Для начала редактирования конкретного узла нужно вызвать у него метод [`BeginEdit`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenode.beginedit?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
treeView1.SelectedNode.BeginEdit();
```

Изменения сохранятся по нажатию Enter.